# Jcarousel and display: none + SEO concern

Tags: javascript, jquery, seo, jcarousel

I am using jcarousel on a page in 3 different sections. I initially show the first section and hide the other two with `display: none`.

I have done some googling and found this is a common problem because anything that has a display of none automatically has a width of 0 and hence jcarousel cannot set it up properly.

I found this post on SO: [Hide a jCarousel when page loads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2112474/hide-a-jcarousel-when-page-loads/2112562#2112562)

That deals with it by putting the content you don't wanna show just yet by moving it off the page, I could do that, but was wondering, would that be bad for SEO purposes? As in Google wouldn't like the content being outside of the page?

Do I have any other options?

Comment: hate to be that guy who questions a question, but why don't you just set the width of the elements in CSS? Or does the script still break?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I fixed my issue by letting the content load first and then once all the page data was loaded I ran a function to hide the relative content.

Code in header.. this runs the `hideHomeCats` function once everything on the page has been loaded.

```
$(window).load(hideHomeCats);
```

Where `hideHomeCats` is a function that hides the relevant content.

Hope this helps someone else. :)